# Silent push notifications work only one time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, completionhandler

I'm building an app that needs to upload a little bit of data every 5 minutes to my Firebase Database.
For that, I'm sending content push notifications with cron.

For the notifications I followed this tutorial : [Push Notification Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)

This is my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in my AppDelegate file :

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(aps["content-available"]!)


    if (aps["content-available"]!).intValue == 1 {
        print("Content notification received")

        //Check if user is logged in or not
        if (loggedIn == false) {
            print("Not logged in, so nothing happens")
            //Maybe call completion handler here ?
        } else {

            //Check the value on the device (works well)
            ViewController().getAValueFromTheDevice()

            //Send the value to the Firebase DB (works only one time in background)
            valueRef.setValue("\(valueFromTheDevice)")

            //Maybe call a completion handler here too ?

        }


    }
```

That's strange because it sends the data only one time while the app is in the background, otherwise, the "local" value check always works.

Also, I noticed that when I use breakpoints with "step-by-step" execution, it always works as expected. Is it linked to the completion handler ?

In my output, when I receive silent notification I have two messages :

> Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

But I don't know what to call in my code...

> FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2

I use Firebase to store real time data but not to send push notifications.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you collecting data every 5 minutes? That kind defeats the purpose of the asynchronous nature of Firebase. Can you leverage that instead and let Firebase tell you when there's new or changed data?

Comment: I don't want to get data from firebase, I want to send data to it.

Comment: Ah, I see. The question states 'fetch' and that generally means to retrieve data from a server. You are not calling the system passed completion handler, hence the message. You should add completionHandler() outside of the if statements.

Comment: The completionHandler() function needs an argument, what should I put ?

Comment: That depends on the intended result. If you are not doing anything with the data you could for example, in the loggedIn == false section use completionHandler(.NoData). In the true section, use completionHandler(.NewData). Or even completionHandler(loggedIn ? .NewData : .NoData) outside of the 'if' check.

Comment: It worked once. I noticed the error `<FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2` appeared just when the notifications are not sending my data to firebase, that's probably linked...

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need or are using FIRMessaging so remove references to that from your App? Otherwise FIRMessaging uses didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Comment: I don't have any reference to FIRMessaging in my app...